# Is it possible to choose which field to edit based on a variable?

Tags: c#, datatable

I'd like to change which DataTable is edited based on how many times a button has been pressed. I have a counter that adds 1 each time the button is pressed. For example, if the button is pressed once, dataTable1 is changed. If twice, dataTable2 is changed.

Upon first being clicked, it should do the same thing as this code:

```
dataTable1.Rows.Add("Test");
```

Theoretically, something like this makes sense, but obviously does not work:

```
dataTable + counter.Rows.Add("Test");
```

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts,

1. I would account for a delay on the button, if the user clicks once and then pauses and then clicks again you should handle that how you want.
2. You could have a dictionary of tables you build on as they click such as:

> ```
>   Dictionary<string, object> tables = new Dictionary<string, object>();
> ```

and then whenever you fire the click event:

> ```
>   tables.Add($"Table{counter}", someData);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of naming all of these DataTable classes "dataTable1" and "dataTable2", consider putting them in a list or an an array.

e.g.

```
DataTable[] dataTables = new [] { dataTable1, dataTable2, dataTable3 };

void MyThing()
{
    dataTables[counter].Rows.Add("Test");
}
```